# How to get the Robot's pose in the Rviz?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using moveit these days, but a problem confused me.
The moveit-rviz plugin is very useful for visualization the robot's planning scene,  there is a demo in the pr2_moveit_config launch file, you can use your mouse to drag the interactive marker on the robot model in Rviz. But I want to get the pose information when I drag or move the endeffector. When I use the getTargetPose, I just return the Target Pose you defined in the code, but how to get the simulation model's pose in realtime?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251161/how-to-get-the-robot%27s-pose-in-the-rviz?/) by [cxxzju](https://answers.ros.org/users/28938/cxxzju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

O I find a solution. When you use rviz as a plugin for moveit, actually you are using the interactive marker srv to send pose information between  interactive marker server and RViz.
The topic use here is update and feedback. So you just need to find the topics when you are running.

[image description http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers:%20Getting%20Started?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=interactive_marker_architecture.png](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers:%20Getting%20Started?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=interactive_marker_architecture.png)

So use "rostopic list" command,  I find there is a topic named /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_maker_topic/feedback
This is just the information I need.

[image: 111.png]

---

Originally posted by [cxxzju](https://answers.ros.org/users/28938/cxxzju/) with karma: 16 on 2017-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UR5e](https://answers.ros.org/users/46501/ur5e/) on 2019-10-17**:
I am trying to get also the current pose position in x,y,z,rx,ry,rz and I have listed the node that you mention. However, neither rostopic echo nor info returns the desired pose. How do you get the pose? Thank you

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2021-02-24**:
you get selected joint's position and orientation information, how can i get all joint angles when i move interactive marker